# TortoiseSVN: got warning message when update file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have used TortoiseSVN  to check out the source code from the server, Today I changed  one file: `theme.css` on my local computer, instead click `commit`, I clicked `update`, afterwards, I got a warning message, then exclamatory mark added on my file: `theme.css`, and got three more files: `theme.css.mine, theme.css.r3588, theme.css.r3656` and in `theme.css`, I saw at the beginning there is `<<<<<<< .mine`, and at the end there is `>>>>>>> .r3656`, so what happened here? and what should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard conflict handling for SVN, It means the file you tried to update has changes on it that conflicted with the version currently on the server.  It adds the `<<<<<` and `>>>>>` carots around the areas that are in conflict.  You need to use a conflict merge tool (TortoiseSVN comes with one but you can download and use others if you like).  Right click your conflicted file and choose the option to edit conflicts, then make edits to resolve the conflicts and save a new final file that doesn't contain all the conflict symbols.